# Why can't I see my object when I start the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, camera

I started using Blender a few days ago but I've got stuck with the camera.
I'm trying to make a simple maze game with a moving cube as character, using some tutorials and this is the result.

[image]

The selected camera you see is one I added by hand: I deleted the default one and added this with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > add camera > etc...
The problem is it doesn't render anything when I press <kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

I've tried making the camera active by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and It seems to be active indeed, but I still get nothing at all!

Comment: First of all I suggest to switch on texture mode(the little menu right of "object mode"). Then ensure you see something through the camera in Blender 3D window. Newly added cameras are often placed at the scene origin (0,0,0) with nothing to see.

Comment: I really don't understand. If I take the default project, then delete the camera and add it again, it wors. Here I've only added a plane, subdivided it, selected the tiles which would be the walls and then pressed "e" and "5".
If i follow your indication I get something in "texture mode"... and it still doesn't render, and I can assure you the camera is not in 0,0,0 ahahah

Comment: No the texture mode is not the cause ;). It was just a hint. There can be a few reasons why you can't see anything. To investigate further I suggest to add a cube in front of the camera and see if that is visible. This way we can tell it the camera sees anything.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's not invisible in physics.

Make sure the normals are facing the correct direction.

Comment: Your answer is being flagged as low-quality. Perhaps you could consider adding some more detail, such as an image or additional instructions illustrating how to do these things.